# SSRS ReportViewer URL in CRM Ribbon

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I've added a button to print a SSRS report to one of my CRM ribbons.  The only issue is that every time it calls the URL the path is removed from the url parameters. For example the URL I have in the XML is:

```
<CommandDefinition Id="Company.Form.quote.MainTab.Actions.PrintQuote.Command">
      <EnableRules />
      <DisplayRules />
      <Actions>
        <Url Address="http://<Server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Test/ReportName">
          <CrmParameter Name="QuoteId" Value="FirstPrimaryItemId" />
          <StringParameter Value="Render" Name="rs:Command" />
          <StringParameter Name="rs:Format" Value="PDF" />
        </Url>
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
```

And the URL it navigates to is:

```
http://<server>/ReportServer?QuoteId=%7bE6D8DC8B-6381-E411-80BC-00155D18D500%7d&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs%3aFormat=PDF
```

It seems that I need a name for the ItemPath, but ReportServer doesn't accept one I know of, is there a way around this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround,

I did the same thing, just instead of putting the URL in the CommandDefinition I used javascript to redirect.